# How to calculate the exterior derivative on manifolds of smooth mappings?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, moment-map

Let $S$ be a compact finite-dimensional manifold $S$ and $(M, \omega)$ a symplectic manifold. The space of smooth maps from $S$ to $M$, denoted by $\mathcal{M}$, has a canonical infinite-dimensional manifold structure. Thus, the tangent space of $\mathcal{M}$ at a map $f$ is the space of smooth sections of $f^*(TM)$ over $S$.

In his paper "Moment maps and diffeomorphisms", Donaldson defines a 2-form on $\mathcal{M}$ by $$\Omega(v, w) = \int_{S} \omega(v, w) \,\sigma,$$ where $v,w$ are sections of $f^*(TM)$ and $\sigma$ is a volume form on $S$. He goes on to claim $\Omega$ is symplectic.

Of course, non-degeneracy and anti-symmetry are straightforward to prove. However, I haven't been able to prove it is closed. I've tried using the invariant formula $$d\Omega (X,Y,Z) = X(\Omega(Y,Z)) - Y(\Omega(X,Z)) + Z(\Omega(X,Y)) - \Omega([X,Y],Z) + \Omega([X,Z],Y) - \Omega([Y,Z], X),$$ which I know for a fact works for infinite-dimensional manifolds. However, I am having trouble calculating the Lie brackets and applying the vector fields to the evaluated $\Omega$.

Does anyone know another way to prove $\Omega$ as defined above is closed?

Comment: I think you are missing the very obvious approach of doing the calculation in coordinate charts (both for $M$ and $C^\infty(S,M)$), which should give you $d\Omega(u,v,w) = \int_S d\omega(u,v,w) \, \sigma$.